# ol3 bind feature point and feature type linestring

Tags: javascript, bind, openlayers-3, marker

I didn't succeed to find a sample code or something like that to help me to code a functionality. To explicate shortly, on a map I added 3 features :

- 2 type point
- 1 type linestring between both
  I enabled the drag capacity.

I don't know if it is  possible, I would like bind directly the features 'point' to the feature 'linestring'. I would like drag a feature and that the linestring redraw automatically.

I already tried to code with 'Drag.prototype.handleDragEvent ', but I think that the latency is not really good.

Comment: Are you looking for a straight line between the two point or an irregular line which follows the cursor?

Comment: I'm looking for a straight line between the two point.

Comment: Then I think you'll have to fake a draw. See https://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/8b322285/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I already look this code. But error excepted, it'is not possible to drag one side of one linestring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was easier than I thought (initially). See **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/70vsd0of/)**.

Make use of `translating` of [`ol.interaction.Translate`](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.interaction.Translate.html) and then tell you linestring that the current coordinate is its last coordinate.

The relevant code is:

```
translate1.on('translatestart', function (evt) {
  coordMarker2 = marker2.getCoordinates();
});

translate1.on('translating', function (evt) {
  line.setCoordinates([coordMarker2, evt.coordinate]);
});

translate2.on('translatestart', function (evt) {
  coordMarker1 = marker1.getCoordinates();
});

translate2.on('translating', function (evt) {
  line.setCoordinates([coordMarker1, evt.coordinate]);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't search with the good keyword, I searched with 'bind', 'attach'... not thought at 'translate'